# C++ derived class constructor issue

Tags: c++, constructor

I am having some issues with my constructor as currently only the base constructor is being used for some reason my multiple argument constructors are not being used. Creature is my abstract grandparent class, while combatant is derived from creature and goblin is derived from combatant

```
combatant fighter_1;
combatant fighter_2;
do
{
    cout << "Please pick the first combatant, enter 1 for a Goblin, \n";
    cout << "enter 2 for a Barbarian, enter 3 for a Reptile person, \n" ;
    cout << "enter 4 for a Blue Men, enter 5 for a Beserker, \n";
    cout << "enter 6 for a hobbit. \n";
    cin >> pick;
    checker=pick;
        if (cin.fail()||checker!=pick||pick<1||pick>6)
        {
            cout << "You have entered an invalid input.\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            pick=-1;
        }
}
while (checker!=pick||pick<1||pick>6); //makes sure number entered is valid
if (pick==1)
{
goblin fighter_1("Goblin",6,6,0,6,0,0,3,8);
}
```

I have one constructor for each creature class but each one acts the same as the goblin

```
creature::creature(): chartype("no name yet"), adice1(0), 
adice2(0), adice3(0),ddice1(0), ddice2(0), ddice3(0), defense(0),health(0)
{

}

combatant :: combatant(): creature()
{

}



creature::creature( string name, int attack1, int attack2, int attack3, int def1, int    def2,
int def3, int defense, int health): chartype(name), adice1(attack1), adice2(attack2), 
adice3(attack3),ddice1(def1), ddice2(def2), ddice3(def3),  defense(defense),health(health)
{

}

combatant::combatant(string name, int attack1, int attack2, int attack3, int def1, int  def2,
int def3, int defense, int health) :creature(name, attack1, attack2, attack3, def1, def2,
def3, defense, health)
{

}


goblin::goblin(string name, int attack1, int attack2, int attack3, int def1, int def2,
int def3, int defense, int health) :combatant(name, attack1, attack2, attack3, def1, def2,
def3, defense, health)
{

}
```

Comment: You should be using pointers and memory allocation for this. Preferably a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Just fyi: `goblin fighter_1("Goblin",6,6,0,6,0,0,3,8);` doesn't magically make the `fighter_1` in the outer scope a goblin. All it does it construct one locally with a name that hides the outer, then promptly throws it away. Nothing in the `combatant  fighter_1` changes *at all*. If you're gauging no change in that var as proof the if-block didn't execute, it isn't such (proof).

Comment: I picked up this code from a few months ago and realized I was not going off the most recent version I should have it as fighter_1=goblin("Goblin",6,6,0,6,0,0,3,8);

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when the single statement in an `if` body is not executed (as you report is the case here), it's due to the `if` condition not being `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I picked up this code from a few months ago and realized I was not going off the most recent version I should have it as

```
fighter_1 = goblin("Goblin",6,6,0,6,0,0,3,8);
```

Comment: That assignment causes slicing.